# Как сгенерировать класс из Json?

Tags: c#, json

```
Сервис выдает данные в формате json 
{  
   "request":{  
      "Target":"Offer",
      "Format":"json",
      "Service":"HasOffers",
      "Version":"2",
      "NetworkId":"22",
      "NetworkToken":"33",
      "Method":"findAll",
      "limit":"3",
      "page":"10"
   },
   "response":{  
      "status":1,
      "httpStatus":200,
      "data":{  
         "page":"10",
         "current":27,
         "count":40269,
         "pageCount":13423,
         "data":{  
            "58":{  
               "Offer":{  
                  "id":"58",
                  "display_advertiser":"0",
                  "advertiser_id":"500",
                  "name":"name1",
                  "description":"",
                  "require_approval":"0",
                  "require_terms_and_conditions":0,
                  "terms_and_conditions":null,
                  "preview_url":"",
                  "offer_url":"",
                  "currency":null,
                  "default_payout":"0.02000",

               }
            },
            "60":{  
               "Offer":{  
                  "id":"60",
                  "display_advertiser":"0",
                  "advertiser_id":"500",
                  "name":"name2",
                  "description":"",
                  "require_approval":"0",
                  "require_terms_and_conditions":0,
                  "terms_and_conditions":null,
                  "preview_url":"http:\/\/wap.mozzi.com\/ES_FRIENDFINDER\/affid=YZM&sem=N",
                  "offer_url":"http:\/\/wap.mozzi.com\/ES_FRIENDFINDER\/affid=YZM&sem=N&transaction_id={transaction_id}&pubid={pub_id}",
                  "currency":null,
                  "default_payout":"0.05000",

               }
            }
         }
      },
      "errors":[  

      ],
      "errorMessage":null
   }
}
```

Через онлайн кодогенератор, да и через встроенный генератор `Visual Studio` выдает следующий вид класса, что по сути не совсем корректно, так как каждый `id` он записывает как свойство класса. Подскажите что я делаю не так?*

```
 public class Request
    {
        public string Target { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }
        public string Service { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string NetworkId { get; set; }
        public string NetworkToken { get; set; }
        public string Method { get; set; }
        public string limit { get; set; }
        public string page { get; set; }
    }

    public class Offer
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string display_advertiser { get; set; }
        public string advertiser_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string require_approval { get; set; }
        public int require_terms_and_conditions { get; set; }
        public object terms_and_conditions { get; set; }
        public string preview_url { get; set; }
        public string offer_url { get; set; }
        public object currency { get; set; }
        public string default_payout { get; set; }
    }

    public class 58
    {
        public Offer Offer { get; set; }
    }

    public class 60
    {
        public  Offer { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public 58 58 { get; set; }
        public 60 60 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string page { get; set; }
        public int current { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
        public int pageCount { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public int status { get; set; }
        public int httpStatus { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
        public IList<object> errors { get; set; }
        public object errorMessage { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public Request request { get; set; }
        public Response response { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Не надейтесь на кодогенератор, допилите классы до нужного состояния вручную.

Comment: В кодогенераторе нельзя делать "цифровое" имя класса, его нужно указать атрибутом.